# Problem using regex to remove number formatting in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having this issue with a regular expression in PHP that I can't seem to crack. I've spent hours searching to find out how to get it to work, but nothing seems to have the desired effect.

I have a file that contains lines similar to the one below:

```
Total','"127','004"','"118','116"','"129','754"','"126','184"','"129','778"','"128','341"','"127','477"','0','0','0','0','0','0
```

These lines are inserted into INSERT queries. The problem is that values like **"127','004"** are actually supposed to be **127,004**, or without any formatting: **127004**. The latter is the actual value I need to insert into the database table, so I figured I'd use preg_replace() to detect values like **"127','004"** and replace them with **127004**.

I played around with a Regular Expression designer and found that I could use the following to get my desired results:

**Regular Expression**

```
"(\d+)','(\d{3})"
```

**Replace Expression**

```
$1$2
```

The line on the top of this post would end up like this: (which is what I am after)

```
Total','127004','118116','129754','126184','129778','128341','127477','0','0','0','0','0','0
```

This, however, does not work in PHP. Nothing is being replaced at all.

The code I am using is:

```
$line = preg_replace("\"(\d+)','(\d{3})\"", '$1$2', $line);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is your code fails only after last?

Comment: is your code fails only after the line on the top of this post  regexp? or even whithout that line regexp it doesn't work?

Comment: Actually it does work, see [here](http://ideone.com/NIqyS).

Comment: As it turns out, I'm using preg_replace in the wrong part of my code. Thanks a lot to the both of you! I wouldn't have noticed otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no delimiters in your regex. Delimiters are required in order for PHP to know what is the pattern to match and what is a pattern modifier (e.g. i - case-insensitive, U - ungreedy, ...). Use a character that doesn't occur in your pattern, typically you'll see a slash '/' used.

Try this:

`$line = preg_replace("/\"(\d+)','(\d{3})\"/", '$1$2', $line);`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your regular expression in front-slashes.  Try this instead:

```
"/\"(\d+)','(\d{3})\"/"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_replace("#\"(\d+)','(\d+)\"#", '$1$2', $s);` instead of yours